# Can't call result() on futures in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I want to do some asynchronous HTTP-requests using the python library tornado (version 4.2). I can however not force a future to complete (using `result()`) since I get an Exception: "DummyFuture does not support blocking for results".

I have python 3.4.3 therefore future support should be part of the standard library. The documentation of `concurrent.py` says:

> Tornado will use `concurrent.futures.Future` if it is available;
>   otherwise it will use a compatible class defined in this module.

A minimal example for what I am trying to do is provided below:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient;

future = AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("http://google.com")
future.result()
```

If I understand my problem correctly it occurs because the import of `concurrent.futures.Future` somehow is not used. The relevant code in tornado appears to be in `concurrent.py` but I am not really making progress on understanding where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: The comment "Tornado will use concurrent.futures.Future if available" is outdated; Tornado 4.x always uses its own Future implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create another `Future` and use `add_done_callback`:

[From Tornado documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html#asynchronous)

```
from tornado.concurrent import Future

def async_fetch_future(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    my_future = Future()
    fetch_future = http_client.fetch(url)
    fetch_future.add_done_callback(
        lambda f: my_future.set_result(f.result()))
    return my_future
```

But you still need **solve the future with the ioloop**, like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tornado.concurrent import Future
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


def async_fetch_future():
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    my_future = Future()
    fetch_future = http_client.fetch('http://www.google.com')
    fetch_future.add_done_callback(
        lambda f: my_future.set_result(f.result()))
    return my_future

response = IOLoop.current().run_sync(async_fetch_future)

print(response.body)
```

Another way to this, is using `tornado.gen.coroutine`decorator, like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


@coroutine
def async_fetch_future():
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    fetch_result = yield http_client.fetch('http://www.google.com')
    return fetch_result

result = IOLoop.current().run_sync(async_fetch_future)

print(result.body)
```

`coroutine` decorator causes the function to return a `Future`.

Comment: This works for me, thanks! I think I got it. I can't use 'raw' futures because they are not part of the IOLoop and I'd need some way to add them to that. Correct?

Comment: why couldn't you '''def async_fetch_future():
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    my_future = Future()
    fetch_future = http_client.fetch('http://www.google.com')'''   and then put this function into IOLOOP?