# Python generators and reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, tornado

I am working on a Python3 `tornado` web server with asynchronous coroutines for GET requests, using the `@gen.coroutine` decorator. I want to use this function from a library:

```
@gen.coroutine
def foo(x):
    yield do_something(x)
```

which is simple enough:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    x = self.some_parameter
    yield response(foo(x))
```

Now assume there are multiple functions `foo1`, `foo2`, etc. of the same type. I want to do something like `...foo3(foo2(foo1(x).result()).result())...` and `yield` that instead of just `response(foo(x))` in the `get` method.

I thought this would be easy with `reduce` and the `result` method. However, because of how `tornado` works, I cannot force the `foo`s to return something with the `result` method. This means that `yield reduce(...)` gives an error: "DummyFuture does not support blocking for results". From other answers on SO and elsewhere, I know I will have to use `IOLoop` or something, which I didn't really understand, and...

...my question is, how can I *avoid evaluating **all** the `foo`s* and `yield` that unevaluated chunk from the `get` method?

*Edit*: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172272) because I want to: 1. nest a lot of functions and 2. try *not* to evaluate immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't call result() on futures in tornado](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172272/cant-call-result-on-futures-in-tornado)

Comment: If you mean return a function(-like) object that simulates that nesting, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python) is the proper duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tornado, you must `yield` a Future inside a coroutine in order to get a result. Review [Tornado's coroutine guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html).

You could write a reducer that is a coroutine. It runs each coroutine to get a Future, calls `yield` with the Future to get a result, then runs the next coroutine on that result:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen


@gen.coroutine
def f(x):
    # Just to prove we're really a coroutine.
    yield gen.sleep(1)
    return x * 2


@gen.coroutine
def g(x):
    return x + 1


@gen.coroutine
def h():
    return 10


@gen.coroutine
def coreduce(*funcs):
    # Start by calling last function in list.
    result = yield funcs[-1]()

    # Call remaining functions.
    for func in reversed(funcs[:-1]):
        result = yield func(result)

    return result


# Wrap in lambda to satisfy your requirement, to 
# NOT evaluate immediately.
latent_result = lambda: coreduce(f, g, h)
final_result = IOLoop.current().run_sync(latent_result)
print(final_result)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Could you please explain what happens inside the coreduce function with the multiple yield and return statements?

Comment: Each "yield" waits for the called coroutine to complete, and resolves the Future it returns into a result. The "return" statement returns a value from the coroutine. Whatever a coroutine returns becomes the value of its Future.

Comment: "Whatever a coroutine returns becomes the value of its Future.": this is the most helpful statement I've heard so far about coroutines. Thank you very much!