# Tornado: DummyFuture does not support blocking for results

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to get a very simple initial server which fetches a url (asynchronously) to work but it throws:

```
Exception: DummyFuture does not support blocking for results
```

There's this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172272/cant-call-result-on-futures-in-tornado) post but the answers do not include running a web server and trying to add the future to my loop as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31172384/1252307) throws:

```
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
```

This is the complete code:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

URL = 'http://stackoverflow.com'


@tornado.gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    raise tornado.gen.Return(response.body)  # Python2


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


class FetchSyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = fetch_coroutine(URL)
        print type(data)  # <class 'tornado.concurrent.Future'>
        self.write(data.result())


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/async", FetchSyncHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(9999)
    print 'starting loop'
    IOLoop.current().start()
    print 'loop stopped'
```

The loop is running, a future is returned. What is the issue?

Python **2.7.10**
tornado==**4.4.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a result from a Future, `yield` it in a `gen.coroutine` function, or `await` it in an `async def` native coroutine. So replace your FetchSyncHandler with:

```
class FetchSyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        data = yield fetch_coroutine(URL)
        self.write(data)
```

For more information, see the my [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/) or the [Tornado coroutine guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html).