# Error using async in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am now implementing the async query in tornado, and facing some problems. My code always returns **DummyFuture does not support blocking for results**. Googled some posts and it's seems I didn't add the return response into `Future`. Try to modify my code but it still returns the same error. Please help to check my code.

```
from tornado import httpclient

query_url = 'https://some_url.com'
http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

def request(query_url):
    resp = yield(http_client.fetch(query_url, method="GET"))
    raise Return(resp.body)

response = request(query_url)
do_something_for_response(response)
```

My expected `response` should be a json format and in the function `do_something_for_response`, it handles the json and return to outside.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't change the framework.

Comment: you need to make `request` a coroutine and the whole chain of calls which leads to `request` too. Also a `ioloop` is required to make async calls work correctly. Try to use https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/webspider/webspider.py as a start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tornado: DummyFuture does not support blocking for results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425318/tornado-dummyfuture-does-not-support-blocking-for-results)

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov, do you mean that I need to add `@gen.coroutine` before every functions from beginning to the end of a query?