# Can't Call result on futures tornado , always result object

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, tornado

```
from somefolder import somelibrary

@gen.coroutine
def detailproduct(url):
    datafromlib=yield somelibrary(url)
    raise gen.Return(datafromlib)
```

expectation:
See the result without request handler.
not result like

```
{"data":<tornado.concurrent.future>}
```

I try like this link:
"[Can't call result() on futures in tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172272/cant-call-result-on-futures-in-tornado)"
But not work.

Somebody help me! tx

Answer (score 1):

There are the two rules that you've to keep in mind while working with `gen.coroutine`:

1. `gen.coroutine` decorated functions will automatically return a Future.
2. If a function/coroutine is calling another coroutine decorated with `gen.coroutine`, it must also be decorated with `gen.coroutine` and must use the `yield` keyword to get its result.

`detailproduct` is decorated with `gen.coroutine` - which means it will always return the `datafromlib` wrapped in a Future.

---

**How to fix**

According to Rule 2, you've to decorate the caller with `gen.coroutine` and use the `yield` keyword to get the result of the Future.

```
@gen.coroutine
def my_func():
    data = yield detailproduct(url) 
    # do something with the data ...
```

OR

You can set a callback function on the Future that will be called when it gets resolved. But it makes the code messy.

```
def my_fun():
    data_future = detailproduct(url)
    data_future.add_done_callback(my_callback)

def my_callback(future):
    data = future.result()
    # do something with the data ...
```